# "sh: : unknown operand" in Yocto

Tags: shell, yocto

The following works in Ubuntu but not Yocto (Poky).

```
root@system:~/# x='abc'
root@system:~/# y=''
root@system:~/# [[ $(echo $x) != '' ]] && echo true
true
root@system:~/# [[ $(echo $y) != '' ]] && echo true
sh: : unknown operand
```

In Ubuntu the last line returns nothing (as expected).  Any ideas why it's throwing an error in Yocto?

Comment: I'm betting that `sh` is not the same on those two platforms and that on Yocto it's not as fully implemented, I was actually surprised that `sh` implemented `[[` at all, Yocto or otherwise

Comment: Ubuntu has dash as sh, while an image built with OpenEmbedded often has busybox as sh.

Comment: @eric-renouf Any idea exactly what the problem can be though, considering it works in Yocto for `$x`?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is how it handles "empty" args, so as long as you have a value on each side of `!=` it will work.  You might just try quoting the command substitutions like `[[ "$(echo $y)" != '' ]]...` and see if that helps

Comment: @EricRenouf That works thanks Eric. Want to add as the answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `$(echo $y)` is expanding to an empty string, and then `[[` isn't handling it correctly.  The solution to that would be to quote the command substitution like

```
[[ "$(echo "$y")" != '' ]] && echo true
```

though it's probably better still to use [printf than echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) so you might do it as

```
[[ "$(printf '%s' "$y")" != '' ]] && echo true
```

just in case `$y` might end up with special characters that can trip up `echo` or similar

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, busybox ash has a rather simplistic implementation of `[[`. It is the same as `[` except that it expects a `]]` instead of `]` final argument. This misses the point of why `[[` can be useful at all: `[[` is supposed to be a keyword with special parsing and using it looks more beautiful and avoids various pitfalls (while adding some of its own). I guess they added it so a few more bash scripts run unmodified on busybox ash.

To avoid confusion, I recommend not using `[[` in busybox at all. Use `[` and quote all command substitutions and parameter expansions.